# Error: cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: rpmfusion-free

Tags: yum, centos

I have a VPS; I tried to run this command in CentOS 6.5 32 bits:

```
sudo yum install sd-agent
```

And I get:

```
Loaded pluings: fasestmirrors
Determining fastest mirrors
Error: cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: rpmfusion-free
```

I have try to update yum but I get the same error.

If I try to `ping` or `gid` a host, it all works fine.

How I can fix this error?

Comment: Did you add `rpmfusion-free` to the repo list? VPS providers often use their own repos, and may have some mechanism to prevent you from using one from outside.

Comment: Try doing `yum update --disablerepo=rpmfusion` first, it might be some glitch in older installed packages. As @goldilocks says, check the configuration of the repository, it might me wrong. Perhaps reinstall the package providing it.